# delay and interval operators do not work properly

Tags: java, observable, rx-java2

As shown below, I am creating `Observables`. I would like to wait specific amount of time in seconds as shown in the code. therefore I used either delay or interval
operator. I expected the code to wait i.e. 5 seconds then `System.out.println` from the observer to be printed.

but what happens is, `doOnNext` is executed and the code never goes further. I mean the execution stops at `doOnNext` even after the 5 seconds elapsed.

**Code**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable<List<Person>> observables = Observable.create(e-> {
        for(List<Person> p : Main.getPersons()) {
            e.onNext(p);
        }
        e.onComplete();
    });
     observables
    //.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())//newThread
    .flatMap(p->Main.toObservable(p.get(0).getName()))
    .doOnNext(p-> System.out.println(p.length()) )
    .map(p->p+"..STRING")
    //.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    //.interval(0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(new Observer() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("onCompleted");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Object arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("onNextFromObserver: " + arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}

private static <T> Observable<T> toObservable(T s) {
    return Observable.just(s);
}

private static List<List<Person>> getPersons() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList(new Person("Sanna1", 59, "EGY"), new Person("Sanna2", 59, "EGY"), new Person("Sanna3", 59, "EGY")),
            Arrays.asList(new Person("Mohamed1", 59, "EGY"), new Person("Mohamed2", 59, "EGY")),
            Arrays.asList(new Person("Ahmed1", 44, "QTR"), new Person("Ahmed2", 44, "QTR"), new Person("Ahmed3", 44, "QTR")),
                    Arrays.asList(new Person("Fatma", 29, "KSA")),
                    Arrays.asList(new Person("Lobna", 24, "EGY"))
                    );
}
```

Comment: Why are you posting the same problem over and over? You have to wait in the `main` method. Put `Thread.sleep(10000)` at the very end of the `main()` method so the `Observable` has chance to run. RxJava threads are daemon threads that stop when the application thread falls out of the `main()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait in the main method. Put `Thread.sleep(10000)` at the very end of the `main()` method so the `Observable` has chance to run. RxJava threads are daemon threads that stop when the application thread falls out of the `main()` method.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Observable.just("Hello World!", "Keep printing values!")
    .zipWith(Observable.interval(0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS), (a, b) -> a)
    .subscribe(v -> 
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + ": " + v)
    );

    Thread.sleep(10000);  // <-----------------------------------

}
```

Comment: thanks but after i tried your code..both values inside just operator are getting displayed at the same time...i want to know how to add delay between each emitted values

Comment: Updated the answer, zip with an interval. If you need at least 5 seconds between items which arrive uneven, use [spanout](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowabletransformersspanout).

Comment: thanks would you please tell me what does a nd b indicate??

Comment: They are the values from each source, the main (a) and the interval (b). Zip fires when both sources have a value and you want to continue with (a).